# How do I center the login information in the middle of this login box?

Tags: html, css

I'm testing some scenarios with flexbox while learning HTML and CSS. I can't for the life of me get the `user-input` div centered in the middle of the `login-box` div. I was able to get it centered vertically with `align-items: center;` but I can't get it to move down without using margins (which I would prefer to avoid).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Login
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="login-box">
                <div class="user-input">
                    <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                    <input class="password" type="text" placeholder="Password">
                    <button class="login-button">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.page-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.login-box {
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.user-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.email,
.password {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: .5px solid black;
}

.login-button {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The `login-box` div is the rectangular shadow box in the middle of the screen. The `user-input` is where I have a column flexbox created.

[image: Here's a screenshot.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change .login box styling:

```css
.page-container {
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .login-box {
        height: 350px;
        width: 250px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .user-input {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .email,
    .password {
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: .5px solid black;
    }

    .login-button {
        height: 25px;
        width: 100px;
        border: none;
        background-color: darkblue;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Login
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="user-input">
                <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                <input class="password" type="text" placeholder="Password">
                <button class="login-button">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS Grid approach. Then, place the contents in the centre.

```
.login-box {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```